# Angular 1.5.x "angular.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" Error

Tags: angularjs, express

I'm following the "MEAN Machine" book and I'm trying to set up a Angular with Express but I keep running into this error when I'm calling Angular.min.js:

["Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGBxE.png)

I've been searching around for an hour or so now and haven't been able to fix it.

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfpip.png)

Here's my Express Code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    path = require('path'),
    config = require('./config.js');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/index.html'));
});

app.listen(config.devPort);
console.log('Running on ' + config.devPort);
```

And here's where my index.html where Angular is being called:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <base href="/">
    </head>

    <body ng-app="sample">
        <h1>Welcome to the homepage!</h1>
        <div ng-controller="ScheduleCtrl as schedule">
            <h1 ng-bind="schedule.test"></h1>
        </div>

        <!-- inject:js -->
        <script src="/public/assets/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/public/app/app.js"></script>
        <script src="/public/app/modules/schedule/schedule.controller.js"></script>
        <!-- endinject -->   
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the app.js file:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('sample', []);

})();
```

Here's the schedule.controller.js file:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('sample'),
        .controller('ScheduleCtrl', ScheduleCtrl);

    ScheduleCtrl.$inject = [];

    function ScheduleCtrl() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.test = "Hello World!";
    };
})();
```

EDIT:
I checked my console and the paths for the files are giving me a 304:

```
GET / 304 1.934 ms - -
GET /public/assets/lib/angular/angular.min.js 304 2.262 ms - -
GET /public/app/app.js 304 2.578 ms - -
GET /public/app/modules/schedule/schedule.controller.js 304 2.855 ms - -
```

Comment: Seems like you have an extra `<` somewhere. Try using the non-minified version of Angular and the error output should tell you the line it's complaining about.

Comment: @Lex I switched it to the non-minified version but error output isn't telling me the line it's complaining about. The error output is the same as the minified version.

Comment: Can you post a bit of `schedule.controller.js`? You hold all the keys to diagnosing this issue and the error message is pretty clear that there's a `<` where one is not expected to be.

Comment: @Lex I've edited my post and added the schedule.controller.js file.

Comment: I'm out of ideas then. Sorry I'm not able to help.

Comment: Perform a text search of `<` in these 2 js files, probably it slipped into one of them

Comment: I preformed the search but nothing appeared in the schedule.controller.js or the app.js. @JossefHarush

Comment: search in `angular.min.js` and in `schedule.controller.js`

Comment: @JossefHarush I did a search in angular.min.js but it appears multiple times and it all seems valid. Ex. b=1;b<arguments.length;b++ is the first one that appears with "<"

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the scripts in head tag instead of body tag (or before body tag), you're using AngularJS syntax (ng-app, etc.) before the script is included

Comment: Thanks for replying but I moved my script tags to the head tag and the error still appears.

Comment: Aha did you try before body tag? I also just noticed, did you define angular module and controller in your script?

Comment: In the app.js file i've defined the module as:
angular.module('sample', []);

And the controller has been set in the schedule.controller.js file

Comment: Aha I just saw that app.js is included, it still doesn't work? Can you post your app.js and schedule.controller.js?

Comment: Your syntax for schedule.controller.js is not correct, try this format: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_module

Comment: @AnteTomić That is perfectly valid syntax for defining a controller.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the error:

```
angular
    .module('sample'), <-- this comma should not be here
    .controller('ScheduleCtrl', ScheduleCtrl);
```

Comment: Ah, I've removed the comma but the error is still showing.

Comment: Are you certain the updated .js is being loaded and your browser is not just pulling it from the cache?